# jinclude.h:20:55: fatal error: jconfig.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, jpeg, multimedia

I have downloaded open source code for jpeg encoder named as "jpegsr9a.zip".After unzipping when i try to build the source code it is showing like as follows

"jinclude.h:20:55: fatal error: jconfig.h: No such file or directory".

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to first install libjpeg8-dev. You can use apt-get install command. After this is installed you can build the source code of jpegsr9a

Comment: Thanks shwetha.But while trying with this command "apt-get install libjpeg8-dev" following error i'm getting.                            
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg8-dev : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8-dev (>= 1.1.90+svn722-1ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please do an apt-get update first and then you will have to install all the dependencies required by jpegsr9a using apt-get install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the the `jpeg-8a` library, as this will create the file jconfig.h.

Before you proceed to build `jpeg-encoder`, check the prerequisites and then continue. In this case, you need to compile and install `jpeg-8a`.

Comment: Thanks santhosh.But while trying with this command "apt-get install libjpeg8-dev" following error i'm getting. The following packages have unmet dependencies: libjpeg8-dev : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8-dev (>= 1.1.90+svn722-1ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. –  Ravichandran

Comment: use `-f` option along with `apt-get` to fix broken packages

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue compiling a code with the `g++ -m32` (32 bit) flag on a 64 bit system. I fixed it by installing the 32 bit version of the library ie:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev:i386
```

where the suffix `:i386` is used to request the 32-bit version.
If this is your case you should also install the following packages

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

Thanks